# Увеличение шрифта для сообщений компилятора Delphi XE7-DX10, в окне Messages, режим run-time или другой режим, способ и т.п

Tags: delphi, ide, шрифты

Преамбула: "Мартышка к старости слаба глазами стала..." (с) И.С.К.

Как можно увеличить шрифт в Студиях XE8-DX10, в окне Messages, куда сообщения об ошибках и хинты выводятся ?

В редакторе я себе подняла до 16, но глазные перемещения из него в Messages и обратно, здоровья не добавляют.

Думала, посмотреть в сторону UISpy, WinSpector, там можно в run-time найти окно, в данном случае Messages и изменить свойства, в данном случае, увеличить шрифт, но эти средства недоступны для Windows 7 х64, либо это средства, поддерживающие .NET platforms.

Где-то прочитала, что шрифт окна вывода сообщений компилятора delphi, захардкожен. И нужно править bds.exe в hex-редакторе, что не есть правильно и мне неизвестно, где вносить правки.

Может какие-то параметры в реестре есть, пусть даже недокументированные ?
Или какие-то эксперты для XE8-DX10, обладают подобными возможностями ?
Может другие идеи предложите ?

Просьба, не предлагать увеличить шрифт в OS Windows - персонализация.
А также не предлагать правку в реестре ModernTheme, этот твик не влияет на отображение шрифта в окне Messages IDE Stuido Delphi.

Comment: А Inspect.exe не пробовали? он вроде как продолжение UISpy(сам проверить не могу). Насчет экспертов: подобной функциональности не видел, но скорее всего очень легко можно реализовать самостоятельно.

Comment: Пробовала все подобные средства, результат нулевой.
По поводу, что "легко реализовать", если бы все программы писались языком. о_О
Странно, что никто не озаботился ранее.
И странно, что разработчики не предусмотрели, а захардкодили размер шрифта.

Answer (score 1):

Цепочка неутешительных выводов:

1. Даже в `RAD 10 Seattle` возможности изменить размер шрифта в окне Messages какими-либо визуальными настройками нет.
   Все дальнейшие действия проводились именно в `RAD 10`.
2. Утилиты типа `WinspectorSpy` сказали, что окно содержимого Messages имеет тип `TBetterHintWindowVirtualDrawTree`, что уже весьма прозрачно говорит о малой вероятности использования "стандартных" свойств типа `TFont`, т.к. всё рисование на `VirtualDrawTree` производится ручками в соответствующих событиях. Сам этот `VirtualDrawTree` расположен на `TMessageViewForm`
3. Из экспертов я являюсь достаточно счастливым пользователем `CnPack` (не подумайте чего - не рекламирую). В них есть возможность запуска собственных скриптов, которые в состоянии кастомизировать IDE. Просмотрев один из примеров, который увеличивает шрифт в `Object Inspector`, я написал слегка расширенный аналог для окна Messages (для Object Inspector хватает простого выставления шрифта его главной форме):

```
program MessagesFont;

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, TypInfo;

  procedure SetFontSize(WinControl: TWinControl);
  var
    i: integer;
    f: TFont;
  begin
    if IsPublishedProp(WinControl, 'font') then
      begin
        f := TFont(GetObjectProp(WinControl, 'font'));
        f.Size:=14;
      end;
    for i := 0 to WinControl.ControlCount-1 do
      if WinControl.Controls[i] is TWinControl then
        SetFontSize(TWinControl(WinControl.Controls[i]));
  end;

var
  MsgForm: TForm;
  I: Integer;
  f: TFont;
begin
  MsgForm := nil;
  for I := 0 to Screen.FormCount - 1 do
  begin
    if Screen.Forms[I].ClassNameIs('TMessageViewForm') then
    begin
      MsgForm := Screen.Forms[I];
      Break;
    end;
  end;

  if MsgForm = nil then
  begin
    ErrorDlg('Messages Not Found.');
    Exit;
  end;

  MsgForm.Caption := 'Font-Changed Messages';
  SetFontSize(MsgForm);
end.
```

К сожалению - в окне Messages увеличивается всё (даже шрифт текста на табах), кроме самих сообщений. В представленном коде я убрал вывод отладочных сообщений, однако нужно сказать, что само окно с типом `TBetterHintWindowVirtualDrawTree` успешно находится и ему успешно устанавливается размер шрифта.

Вынужден сделать общий вывод - размер и стиль шрифта в панели, отображающей `Messages` экспертами задать вряд ли получится, раз даже успешная установка параметров в 'runtime' не дает нужного эффекта.

Comment: Прошу прощения за долгое молчание. @kami, огромное спасибо и респект, за столь тщательное изучение вопроса и погружение в проблему.
Мне, в свою очередь, удалось нарыть такую штуку:
Try dumping the defnition of the TBetterHintWindowVirtualDrawTree component, in the unit uRttiHelper exist a method called DumpTypeDefinition which uses the RTTI to extract the definition of the components, from here you can see all the availables properties.
Данный юнит входит в состав Delphi-IDE-Colorizer, доступен на GiHub, допилен до DX10.1 Berlin. Буду сама копать в том направлении...